# Conditional loop date lookup SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

If I have two tables, first one is `WorkTime`:

```
ID  EmpNAME     Hours/Day   Date0
1   Mark           7    2015-12-01
2   George         8    2015-12-01
3   Jennifer       6    2015-12-03
4   Mark           5    2015-12-08
5   Jennifer       6    2015-12-08
```

and the second one contains unique names is `EmpName`:

```
ID  EmpNAME
1   Mark
2   George
3   Jennifer
```

Excepted output will repeat all unique names table for each particular existing date with null values if the name did not exist in this date like below table

```
 EmpNAME    Hours/Day     Date0
    Mark         7        2015-12-01
    George       8        2015-12-01
    Jennifer    null    **2015-12-01**
    Mark        null    **2015-12-03**
    George      null    **2015-12-03**
    Jennifer     6        2015-12-03
    Mark         5        2015-12-08
    George      null    **2015-12-08**
    Jennifer     6        2015-12-08
```

How can I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example of solution, which give you expected result:

```
SELECT EmpNAME,[Hours/Day],Date0
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Date0 FROM #WorkTime) D
CROSS JOIN (SELECT EmpNAME FROM #EmpName) EN
OUTER APPLY (SELECT [Hours/Day] FROM #WorkTime wt
             WHERE EN.EmpNAME=wt.EmpNAME AND D.Date0=wt.Date0) HD
ORDER BY Date0
```

At this moment, I don't see other way.